# Merging different worksheets of workbook

Tags: c#, excel, merge, office-interop

The whole app works fine, when merging single tabbed workbooks. But then I added functionality to also merge all worksheets in a book, before merging the book with another.

It merges them (tested on a single multitabbed wbook), but at some point starts to mess it up.
For example

outcome:

- sheet1
  -empty lines- sheet2
  -empty lines- sheet3+ half of sheet4
  -empty lines- sheet2 again not all, with some values missing

etc...

Im not sure if is the code that needs something extra, or problems in certain worksheets.

Heres the crucial parts:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pathList.Count; i++)
{
     List<string> Sheet = GetSheetName(path);
     filename = GetFileName(path);
     MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;'");


     foreach (string SheetName in Sheet)
     {
        //OLEDB SECTION ***********************************************
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" +  SheetName + "$]", MyConnection);
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add(pathList.Count.ToString(), filename);
        MyCommand.Fill(table);
        lstTable.Add(table);
        MyConnection.Close();
        MyCommand.Dispose();
        //*************************************************************
      }

}
```

and the getSheetNames

```
List<string> GetSheetName(string path)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    List<string> names = new List<string>();

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);



    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet i in xlWorkBook.Worksheets)
     if (i.UsedRange.Count > 0)
            names.Add(i.Name);



  return names ;
  }
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but unless I am mistaken, every time you call GetSheetName, you are creating a new Excel instance. That seems a bad idea, you should reuse the same instance if possible.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. i have ti fixed

However, I saved each of the sheets in a new file. I imported them in Access and it happens the same1!

 Every sheet contains fields form another, even when they're separated into different files..

maybe it has to do with the versions? 
I also tried to scan them using Extended Properties='Excel 12.0'.
From 8 and above throws "cannot find installable IMAP'

Comment: Do you want to merge the actual workbooks into one another, or just the data? Since you are opening the workbooks with Interop anyway (which is far more resource intensive than OleDb) you might as well use it to grab the worksheets and copy them into your second workbook, or whichever way around you want it.